# What's the difference between formatting an integer as %d and %s ?

Tags: java, string

While both syntactically valid, are there any important underlying differences one should be aware of between:

```
String result = String.format("Here is a number - %s", someIntValue);
```

vs:

```
String result = String.format("Here is a number - %d", someIntValue);
```

where in both cases `someIntValue` is a `int`?

Comment: `s` just prints it as a String, whereas `d` is only for decimal integers and can be applied with multiple options (e.g. leftpadding with 0 and so on)

Answer (score 12):

For formatter syntax see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

For `%s`:

> If arg implements `Formattable`, then `arg.formatTo` is
>   invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking `arg.toString()`.

`Integer` does not implement `Formattable`, so `toString` is called.

For `%d`:

> The result is formatted as a decimal integer

In most cases the results are the same. However, `%d` is also subject to `Locale`. In Hindi, for example, 100000 will be formatted to १००००० ([Devanagari numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numerals))

You can run this short code snippet to see locales with a "non-standard" output:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales())
{
    String format = String.format(locale, "%d", 100_000);

    if (!format.equals("100000")) System.out.println(locale + " " + format);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `%s` will essentially call the object's `toString()` method. So most probably you will always get the integer as is.

The `%d` is informing the formatter it is actually an integer. There might be Locale specific formatting to abide to if for example it is using a `Locale` which has a different number system etc.

For a demo which illustrates the difference (`%n` generates OS dependant line separator):

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("th", "TH", "TH"));
System.out.printf("%s %n", 42); //output: 42
System.out.printf("%d %n", 42); //output: ๔๒
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case there's no difference, but in general it makes sens to use %s in case if you are not sure about type of value formatted.

Comment: And how would you not know the type of the value (unless you are just passing things of type `Object`... yuck)? This is not PHP ;)

Comment: Exactly for the case when you pass thing of type Object, or if you want to format a variable of generic type ;)

Comment: Well ok, I wouldn't say these are 'general' cases at all. But yes for generic types might be useful. Still if your application is locale sensitive you'll be screwed if you use this approach.

Answer (score -2):

No difference, Both are same because the integer will be taken as String! 
You can't use %d for String but you can use %s for int in String.format!
you can even print the int with System.out.printf(), the integer will simply be parsed as String.

Comment: Nope they are not always the same.

Comment: I was talking about this particular case!

Comment: Yep, and in this particular case you don't know if the code is running on a Thai computer with its default Locale set to thai numbering, or an English one, or some other language. So it is not always the same.

Comment: @jbx To be fair, in this particular case, the OP's format string is "Here is a number - %s". The text that introduces the number is in English and therefore the number should also be printed in English.

Comment: Yes its true. But the whole purpose of the question was to understand whether there are details one should know about when using one instead of the other, since at face value they seem to behave the same under 'common' (western) computer setups. The OP explicitly referred to underlying differences one should be aware of.